# Persistable permissions URI android Q

Tags: android, android-10.0

I'm using the emulator and I send the intent in this way:

```
StorageManager sm = (StorageManager) context.getSystemService(Context.STORAGE_SERVICE);
Intent i;
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
   i = sm.getPrimaryStorageVolume().createOpenDocumentTreeIntent();
} else {
   return null;
}
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION);
```

and in `onActivityResult()`:

```
Uri uri = data.getData();
if (uri == null)
    return null;
context.getContentResolver()
                .takePersistableUriPermission(uri,
                        Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
```

Every time I reboot, the app doesn't have access. Can anyone confirm about this bug on beta 6 on the emulator? Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: This code does not create an `Intent` on Android Q. You `return null` instead.

Comment: Why? The code checks for >= Q

Comment: Whoops, sorry, I mentally inverted the `if` check. Note that none of the flags are relevant there -- those are for those offering a `Uri` to others, not for consumers of a `Uri`, as is your case here.

Comment: oh ok, thanks, I will remove them then. I'm checking via DocumentFile.fromRootUri() canRead() canWrite() methods if I can use the uri but I don't understand why it doesn't work after reboot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I converted your code snippets into this Kotlin activity:

```
package com.commonsware.jetpack.myapplication

import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.SharedPreferences
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.storage.StorageManager
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.documentfile.provider.DocumentFile

private const val PREF_URI = "uri"
private const val REQUEST_SAF = 1337

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
  private val prefs: SharedPreferences by lazy {
    getSharedPreferences("test", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
  }

  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val uriString = prefs.getString(PREF_URI, null)
    val storageManager = getSystemService(StorageManager::class.java)!!

    if (uriString == null) {
      startActivityForResult(
        storageManager.primaryStorageVolume.createOpenDocumentTreeIntent(),
        REQUEST_SAF
      )
    } else {
      val uri = Uri.parse(uriString)
      val docFile = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(this, uri)

      Toast.makeText(
        this,
        "canRead: ${docFile?.canRead()} canWrite: ${docFile?.canWrite()}",
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG
      ).show()
    }
  }

  override fun onActivityResult(
    requestCode: Int,
    resultCode: Int,
    data: Intent?
  ) {
    val uri = data?.data

    if (uri == null) {
      Toast.makeText(this, "Did not get a Uri??!?", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    } else {
      contentResolver.takePersistableUriPermission(
        uri,
        Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION or Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION
      )

      prefs.edit().putString(PREF_URI, uri.toString()).apply()
      Toast.makeText(this, "OK, run the activity again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }

    finish()
  }
}
```

I then ran the app containing this activity as its launcher activity and chose `Downloads/` as the document tree. Subsequent launches of this activity — both before and after a reboot — show `canRead()` and `canWrite()` both return `true`. This was tested on a Google Pixel running Q Beta 6.

I cannot try this on a Q emulator [because Google](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/139139804), so I cannot confirm if I can reproduce your behavior there. But, the fact that this works as expected on hardware should be a positive sign.

Comment: about emulator: I solved switching to canary channel, I downloaded the newer Android version then I revert to stable channel and downloaded the new image

Comment: I try to avoid that sort of thing where possible. In my case, I need a fairly "normal" environment, since I am writing books and stuff. I worry that too many tricks will give me an environment that does not match that of ordinary developers. But, it is good to know that there is a workaround -- thanks for the info!

Comment: `startActivityForResult` is deprecated.

Comment: @Akito: On `ComponentActivity` and subclasses, yes, now it is (it was not two years ago when I wrote this answer). You can use `ActivityResultContracts` as a wrapper.

Comment: @CommonsWare I posted an answer below which is using the new method. Feedback is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

For those who appreciate the accepted answer, but do not want to use `startActivityForResult`, which was deprecated after the original answer was accepted.

My example shows how to save a file to storage from within your app.

First, create a class-wide variable to hold the `ActivityResultLauncher` information:

```
private lateinit var saveDataResultLauncher: ActivityResultLauncher<String>
```

Then, instead of using the deprecated feature, you can put this, for example, in your `MainActivity`'s `onCreate` fun:

```
/** Backup Website Entries */
saveDataResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.CreateDocument()) {}
```

Make the user choose a location to save a file, after pressing a menu item bound to the functionality implemented above:

```
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    return when (item.itemId) {
      R.id.action_save_file -> {
        saveDataResultLauncher.launch("example.txt")
        true
      }
      else -> super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
  }
```

Comment: The question and accepted solution are not for  `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT`, which is what `ActivityResultContracts.CreateDocument` maps to. You would need to try to use `ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult`, to wrap the `Intent` that we get from `createOpenDocumentTreeIntent()`.